# Finding the depth of a given node in a k-ary tree

Tags: java, tree

I have a k-ary tree, and I need to be able to calculate the depths of the nodes once the tree has been built.

Here's the tree class

```
public class DirectoryTree implements Serializable {

    private TreeNode Root;
    private int numNodes;
    private TreeNode Focus;
    private LocalDateTime date;
    private long totalSizeOnDisk;
```

Heres the TreeNode class:

```
public class TreeNode implements Serializable{

    private FileSystemEntry data;
    private boolean directory;
    private TreeNode parent;
    private ArrayList<TreeNode> children;
    private int numChildren;
    private int nodeKey;
    private int depth;
```

My original idea was to queue up all the nodes of the tree in breadth first order, and using the numNodes variable, pop off a given nodes children and set their depth to be whatever the counter variable is, but that doesnt work since then I cant read the popped nodes in order to find the depth of their children. So it seems I need a recursive algorithm or something like that. Maybe a modified breadth first?:

```
public void BFTree() {

    Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    queue.add(this.Root);
    TreeNode current;
    while ((current = queue.poll()) != null) {
        BFTree(current, queue);
    }
}

private void BFTree(TreeNode n, Queue<TreeNode> queue) {

    System.out.println(n.getData().getName());
    if (n.isDirectory()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            queue.add(n.getChildren().get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can search the tree either depth or breadth first. The key  is that when you need to compute the depth of a node, you always have access to the depth of the parent.  There are many ways to achieve this.

Comment: Depth first search...as you make a recursive call pass the depth of the parent + 1 to set the next depth level.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes a lot of sense... I'll just recursively access each node and make the depth parent + 1. So simple haha. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles on this

I just modified my breadth first traversal with this:

```
if(!n.equals(this.Root)){
        n.setDepth(n.getParent().getDepth() + 1);
}
```

Obviously a given node's depth is just its parent's depth + 1. Root doesn't have a parent, so I just defined it as 0 in the access/base case function